# JLabel not comparing to string

Tags: java, string, if-statement, compare, jlabel

I am going to check if a JLabel is the same as a name of a tv show.

I have the code

```
public int lastEp() {
    if(name.getText() == "Dexter") {
        switch (season) {
        case 1:
            return 12;
        case 2:
            return 12;
        // etc.
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I have checked in console what i get from `name.getText()` and the console prints "Dexter".
Still my if statement wont return true.
`System.out.println(name.getText() == "Dexter")` gives false, while `System.out.println(name.getText() + " " + "Dexter")` gives "Dexter Dexter".
What is happening?

Also bonus question, if anyone know what i should return instead of -1 if no other option fits, if there is a good standard to follow.

Comment: To close as a duplicate: don't use `==` to compare Strings. Use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` String methods instead.

Comment: @nhgrif: it's the automatic message when you simply closevote.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is an extended comment and the question should be closed*

`String`s in Java are compared with `String#equals` not `==`

For example,

```
"Dexter".equals(name.getText())
```

You are currently comparing the object (memory) reference, which will vary rarely be equal

Check out the [Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) trail for more details